# Controller of microservices in Java on same system

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

How do I launch and control multiple microservices on the same system in Java? Is there an existing Java controller that can do this?

I have an application server which consists of multiple microservices that run on the same OS instance/system. Each microservice is spring boot based though there are a few exceptions.  I'm looking for some already written controller which will start each service in order and restart if a service fails. I'm not looking for a container based approach but rather a controller which runs as a process on windows.

I don't want to create and maintain windows service entries for each service as that is error prone and tough to keep configured correctly. Getting the startup order right is also difficult.

I can write one myself but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if I can find something that does what I need.

Comment: "Getting the startup order right is also difficult." - to me this already indicates a design flaw with your microservices approach. I'd try to tackle this first and also look into containerization as this will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Does it? I have a Spring Config server that needs to start first. Then the Spring registry server. Everything else can be started then because they depend on these first two. Why does that indicate a design flaw? I am new to microservices so maybe I missed something.

Comment: I see, so the config server and the registry server would be considered part of your environment then. If these are the only dependencies your microservices have then it should be ok and you "just" need to make sure your enviroment (which includes these 2 servers) is up before starting microservices. Since most of those standard services already have good support for containers I'd suggest looking into that. This will also make it easier to move to cloud etc. if you want to do so later on.